# How to delete lines in text file that contain three dupliate fields (strings sep by spaces)

Tags: text-processing, duplicate

I have a long text file as follows (generated from download links and downloaded filenames):

```
file01 48976 5873987 48976 48976 thdshiesde
file02 29876 589845637 29876 29876 uyjedrty 54
file03 38745 58934 99432 38745 hytug 48
```

etc.

I want to delete the lines that have fields 2, 4 and 5 duplicated.

From the above example I want to produce:

```
file03 38745 58934 99432 38745 hytug 48
```

etc.

(The first two lines contain the necessary duplicate fields required for deletion while the third line does not so it is kept.)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

AWK does this trivially:

```
awk '!($2 == $4 && $4 == $5)'
```